# Shall I cache it?

Tags: c++, optimization

When having a class:

```
class X
  {
  int data_;
  void f()
    {
    //shall I cache var data_? by doing
    int cached = data_
    //and instaed of this:
    if (data_ >= 0 && data_ < 1000 || data_ < 0 && data_ > -1000)//first version
      {
      //do something
      }
    else
      {
      //do somegthing else
      }
    // have this:
    if (cashed >= 0 && cashed < 1000 || cashed < 0 && cashed > -1000)//second version
    // in my opinion this is bad code
      {
      //do something
      }
    else
      {
      //do somegthing else
      }
    }
  };
```

Please see comments in code.
I'm asking this question because my accomplice from university states that this kind of code (line 1) is just a bad code. I think that he's talking rubbish but I'm very interested in your opinion on this subject.
Thank you.

Comment: sorry for the off-topic, I saw the title of your question and my first thought was you found an error in one of Donald Knuth's books :-)

Comment: I guess you mean "cache" in stead of "cash"? And can you alter the post with some indenting please? This is hard to read.

Comment: @FrustratedWithPormsDesing I did the cash instead of cache "error" intentionally to make this title more interesting ;)

Comment: @user583216: Ooops, sorry for making it less "interesting". ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Cached

And unless your data_ variable may change halfway through execution, there is no difference whatsoever between those two code segments.

Comment: +1, the practical case where the first version is bad is if the code is executed in a multithreaded application where _data may be accessed by 2 threads simultaneously.

Comment: Assuming two threads working on the same object, neither version is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Don't optimize unless it is already too slow: Write the clearest, simplest possible code, measure it, and if it is too slow, use tools to discover (not guess) which part is the slowest.  If possible, use a better algorithm before deploying caching & other minor optimizations.  In any case, once you've optimized that part, measure it again, and if it it's still too slow, repeat.

That being said, @Zhais is correct.  There's no functional difference in the two code snippets.

Comment: Measure, measure, think, measure, change, measure, measure, think. +1, there is no point in even worrying about this and in most cases it will have no impact at all if `data_` does not change during the execution. So when it matters, then it is not an issue of performance but rather of correctness.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of optimization is called premature optimization. You should not do optimization like that until it is proven to be the bottleneck.

In the first case the variable is actually used as `this->data_` but you can't be sure because compiler may cache it himself.